# После переноса материалов из joomla 1.5 в joomla 3.8 появились вопросы по работе ЧПУ

Tags: html, css, joomla, cms

В joomla 1.5 ссылки в материале были вида

```
index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=60:maliy-dm&amp;catid=14&amp;Itemid=92
```

но при выводе самой статьи отображались в виде ЧПУ. Каким образом сделать это в joomla 3.8?

Так же интересным образом работает ЧПУ в ситуации, когда есть несколько материалов с одинаковым алиасом, но при этом у них не пересекаются URL, т.к. они находятся в разных категориях материалов... Так вот в этой ситуации в конце алиаса добавляется цифра. Т.е. ссылки выглядят примерно так:

```
http://somehost.ru/somecategory/somealias/
http://somehost.ru/anothercategory/somealias1/
http://somehost.ru/yetanothercategory/somealias2/
```

Можно ли это каким-то образом победить? Joomla 1.5 не добавляла цифр в конце.

P.S. Эти вопрос появились прежде всего по той причине, что были импортированы материалы из старой версии joomla и хотелось бы добиться полного совпадения со старой структурой URL.

Comment: а у вас на Joomla 1.5. случайно не установлен компонент sh404SEF ?

Comment: Нет, тоже на всякий случай проверял этот момент